# NameError: name 'FileCheckpointManager' is not defined while saving model

Tags: tensorflow-federated

after simulating this code of federated learning for image classification, I would like to save my model so I add this two lines

```
ckpt_manager = FileCheckpointManager("model.h5")
ckpt_manager.save_checkpoint(ServerState.from_anon_tuple(state), round_num=2)
```

So here is all my code:

```
import collections
import time

import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.enable_v2_behavior()

import tensorflow_federated as tff

source, _ = tff.simulation.datasets.emnist.load_data()


def map_fn(example):
  return collections.OrderedDict(
      x=tf.reshape(example['pixels'], [-1, 784]), y=example['label'])
def client_data(n):
  ds = source.create_tf_dataset_for_client(source.client_ids[n])
  return ds.repeat(10).shuffle(500).batch(20).map(map_fn)


train_data = [client_data(n) for n in range(10)]
element_spec = train_data[0].element_spec

def model_fn():
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(784,)),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, kernel_initializer='zeros'),
      tf.keras.layers.Softmax(),
  ])
  return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
      model,
      input_spec=element_spec,
      loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])


trainer = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
    model_fn, client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(0.02))

....
NUM_ROUNDS = 11
for round_num in range(2, NUM_ROUNDS):
  state, metrics = trainer.next(state, federated_train_data)
  print('round {:2d}, metrics={}'.format(round_num, metrics))


ckpt_manager = FileCheckpointManager("model.h5")
ckpt_manager.save_checkpoint(ServerState.from_anon_tuple(state), round_num=9)
```

But this error does appear:

```
NameError: name 'FileCheckpointManager' is not defined
```

I will appreciate it if you told me how I solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the code is missing an import for the module with the checkpoint manager.

`FileCheckpointManger` is defined in the `checkpoint_manager` module here: [`tensorflow_federated/python/research/utils/checkpoint_manager.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/research/utils/checkpoint_manager.py).

Try adding an import at the top of the file like this (the following example assumes the tensorflow federated github repo is in the import search path):

```py
from tensorflow_federated.python.research.utils import checkpoint_manager
# ...
ckpt_manager = checkpoint_manager.FileCheckpointManager("model.h5")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but I find this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_federated.python.research' ` knowing that I use Tensorflow-federated version `0.12.0`

Comment: Two notes: the CheckpointManager is not in the pip package, the `research/` directory is not part of official TFF release, support is handled by individual researchers. The error is saying Python doesn't know where `tensorflow_federated/python/research/utils/checkpoint_manager.py.` is. One option would be to clone the github repo locally and run your script in the root directory of the repo.

Comment: I'm very happy for your answer and I thank you very much

Comment: Can you tell me please, Now I find other problem `NameError: name 'ServerState' is not defined` I see this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/research/flars/flars_fedavg.py#L54) but I don't know how use it?  I must clone this github repo locally and run my script in the root directory of the repo ? or how ? thanks